# how to restore win 10 driver from linux

Tags: linux, windows, drivers, bootrepair

I've installed ([Bushound](http://www.perisoft.net/bushound/)) in Win10 and it corrupted my Windows.

My device has a disk driver that Windows repair doesn't recognize.

I want to update Windows driver from Linux itself.

Is it possible? Where do I put what the driver Windows should use for the disk controller?

I know these are the drivers I need:
https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/thinkcentre_drivers/t1rst35ws14_scd30.txt

Comment: Where do I put... C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository   Each driver gets its own folder.  The only issue here is the folder name e1d65x64.inf_amd64_e6cd4539c435c2e1   Note:  How the folder name has some kind of checksum built-in, and I don't know how it is computed.  You could import it on a working copy of windows, and copy the folder from there.  However, other steps **may** be required for windows to recognize them.

Answer (score 0):

**steps that solved my problem but will not answer my question:**

- copied the driver files into usb:

  - iaStorS.inf
  - iaStorS.cat
  - iaStorS.sys
- boot into Win10 USB:
- advanced troubleshoot -> **cmd**:

```
x:\ diskpart  
x:\ list volume  
x:\ exit  
x:\ C:  //#my usb was named as [C:]  
C:\ pnputil -a  iaStorS.inf /install
```

- performed system repair 
  and windows after 2 boots fixed the problem

Comment: Additionally, booting from Windows install DVD,USB, or etc. Getting a command prompt. type **dism image:c:\ /Add-Driver /Driver:<path to driver> /recurse** In cases where the system isn't bootable at all.